# JfreeChart background image not showing up

Tags: java, servlets, jfreechart

I'm creating a chart in a servlet, and it works great.

```
chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Smart Chart", ds, true, true,
                true);
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bgImageStr);

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.CYAN);
        plot.setBackgroundAlpha(0.15f);

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getTitle().setBackgroundPaint(Color.PINK);
        chart.setBackgroundImage(icon.getImage());
```

Problem is, the background image is not showing up.  I've tried the plot and chart bg, and all kinds of other stuff.  It must be simple, anyone see what is wrong?  I'm just using the write to PNG to dump it to the browser.  It shows up fine, with all the color changes, just no image.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the image exists, that your path to the image file is correct? Also, often it is better to use resources rather than files.

Comment: `bgImageStr` should be a file name, is it or is it not?

Comment: YbgImageStr is a filename, and it does exist (if I dump the image to the output stream instead of the chart, the image displays in the browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, OP here, I fixed it.

I was calling the servlet from itself, and it did not like that.  I used a resource (as suggested) and it worked fine without the infinite recursion (imagine that).

Answer (score -1):

apply 
        try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException IntExp)
        {
                //your implementation
        }
before  chart.setBackgroundImage(icon.getImage());